# how to automate text input in ios simulator with sikuli?

Tags: ios, automation, sikuli

We use sikuli for automation testing of our app but have had issues with text input fields. We use the external input functionality to just be able to enter the text instead of actualy pressing the letters on the simulated soft keyboard. The problem with this is that it jams up the next action a bit. When you automate the closing of the soft keyboard, the external keyboard still has focus on the input control and the next click only clears focus and does not trigger a tap/click on whatever automate the click on. We have a work around to simply tap twice but this makes the scripts run longer and we are really trying to speed them up. **What is the best way to handle ios text input with sikuli?**

We have thought about writing a function to enter text via softkeybard automation, and turn the external keyboard off, but did not follow through with that because we figured that would make the scripts take way longer. We also have tried a front end code fix to blur fields when the soft keyboard closes but that has proven to be difficult without introducing other unwanted behavior.

Comment: So you have a ploblem with focussing on a certain part?

Comment: @Tenzin the problem is that collapsing the soft keyboard does not lose focus of the input. And when you click something else, then the focus is lost and the new element does not handle the click. Therefore making sikuly require two clicks to proceed with an action after hiding the keyboard.

Comment: What happens if you use something like `App.focus()`. It is something that is executed faster then a click. I use it a lot to make sure Sikuli is focusing on the right app. Make sure that nothing is in the front of it. I believe `App.focus()` will focus on the main app, not something that hovers above it or something.For example: `App.focus(Notepad)`